# Is there a way to obtain the transfer function from a bode plot on Python? (I know that it is possible on Matlab)

Tags: signal-analysis, python, transfer-function, bode

Quite simply, I have a bode plot obtained from a source signal.
Now I wish to obtain the transfer function.

I know it is possible with Matlab: http://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/examples/frequency-domain-identification-estimating-models-using-frequency-domain-data.html?prodcode=ID&language=en

So, I'm asking if anyone knows if there is a way to do the same with Python and where can I search for it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use the control toolbox that is available in python. You can install it using pip install control

From here you can implement transfer functions, bode plots, step responses etc similar to what you would be accustomed to doing with the Matlab control toolbox.

Here are further details:

https://github.com/python-control/python-control

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I will try to implement it with that package